# Only a single char inserted on stored procedure Insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am using *VS 2008* `Asp.net C#`. To *insert* the data I have created a `stored procedure`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INS_tblRegister
    @Enroll varchar,
    @Name varchar,
    @Dob varchar,
    @Gender varchar,
    @Mobile varchar,
    @Address varchar,
    @Branch varchar, 
    @Sem varchar,
    @Year varchar, 
    @Password varchar
AS
    INSERT INTO tblRegister (Enrollment, Name, Dob, Gender, Mobile, Address, Branch, Sem, Year, Password)       
    VALUES (@Enroll,@Name,@Dob,@Gender,@Mobile,@Address,@Branch,@Sem,@Year,@Password)

    RETURN
```

Below is my code for `button_Click` :

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("INS_tblRegister",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enroll", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEnroll.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Dob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (txtDob.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlGender.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMobile.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Branch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBranch.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Sem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSem.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtYear.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    lblMsg.Text="Saved";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    lblMsg.Visible = true;
    lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

This code was *executed* successfully but when I see the database I found :

[image: Database ScreenShot]

Only the first character of my entry saved eg: look at the Gender field,I wrote Male but only M is inserted to database. Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add character lengths to your stored procedure parameters like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INS_tblRegister

    @Enroll varchar(20),@Name varchar(20),@Dob varchar(20),@Gender varchar(20),@Mobile varchar(20),@Address varchar(20), @Branch varchar(20), @Sem varchar(20), @Year varchar(20), @Password varchar(20)
AS

    INSERT INTO tblRegister (Enrollment, Name, Dob, Gender, Mobile, Address, Branch, Sem, Year, Password)
    VALUES (@Enroll,@Name,@Dob,@Gender,@Mobile,@Address,@Branch,@Sem,@Year,@Password)

    RETURN
```

Answer (score 2):

The default length for CHAR and VARCHAR is 1.

[char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

You need to define the length of VARCHAR in the Signature

```
@MyField VARCHAR(100)
```

Comment: I am sorry but isn't varchar default length is 30 ?

Comment: Thanks previously i encountered default length of `Varchar` with `Cast` function, I hope there i picked the wrong road . Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Declare variables of SP as `@Enroll varchar(size)`, where size is int value. Example`@Enroll varchar(500)`. The varchar will only consider first character since its length is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Provide length of each varchar field.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INS_tblRegister

    @Enroll varchar(10),@Name varchar(50),
@Dob varchar(10),@Gender varchar(6),@Mobile varchar(10),@Address varchar(100),
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the size of **varchar**. Try this procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INS_tblRegister

@Enroll varchar(50),@Name varchar(50), @Dob varchar(50), @Gender varchar(50), @Mobile varchar(50), @Address varchar(50),
@Branch varchar(50), @Sem varchar(50), @Year varchar(50), @Password varchar(50)
AS

INSERT INTO tblRegister(Enrollment, Name, Dob, Gender, Mobile, Address, Branch, Sem, Year, Password) VALUES(@Enroll,@Name,@Dob,@Gender,@Mobile,@Address,@Branch,@Sem,@Year,@Password)

RETURN
```

The default `varchar` size is 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

```
varchar[(n)]
```

When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE INS_tblRegister

@Enroll varchar(20),@Name varchar(20),@Dob varchar(20),@Gender varchar(20),@Mobile varchar(20),@Address varchar(20), @Branch varchar(20), @Sem varchar(20), @Year varchar(20), @Password varchar(20)
AS

INSERT INTO tblRegister (Enrollment, Name, Dob, Gender, Mobile, Address, Branch, Sem, Year, Password)
VALUES (@Enroll,@Name,@Dob,@Gender,@Mobile,@Address,@Branch,@Sem,@Year,@Password)

RETURN
```